# How do I install streamparse from source?

Tags: python, streamparse

I need to use streamparse on a CentOS machine that does not have internet access, meaning I cannot use pip. The only net-enabled services I can use are scp and ssh. My plan is to get streamparse on my local machine (Ubuntu) and then scp the streamparse files to the CentOS machine and manually install from there.

Any ideas on how to do this?

edit:
since this is "on hold as off-topic," I'll explain why it just might be considered "on topic" by addressing the 4 "on topic" bullet points from the community help page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

1. a specific programming problem: installation is a kind of programming problem, especially when you have to write (program, verb) shell scripts (program, noun) to accomplish the installation of software that leads to more programming.
2. a software algorithm: I am looking for a sequence of steps (aka an algorithm) to install something within specified technical constraints.
3. software tools commonly used by programmers: the thing I am trying to 
   install is a software tool. It is called streamparse. It is used by programmers.
4. a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development: I was not asking this question for theoretical reasons--hence it is practical, and I believe installing things by getting around firewalls is unique to software development. I'll concede that this *could* be viewed not as "software development" but rather "devops" but those two things are merging so throw me a bone here.

Comment: If you find a solution, don't edit it into the question. Add an answer of your own instead.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks. I mv'd the edit to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the lib files on the CentOS box you can use pip to install by passing the `-e` (editable) flag:

```
$ pip install -e path/to/SomeProject
```

Here's a [link to pipy's #editable-installs section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @dougdragon. I also got pointed to the solution below. I'll leave yours as the accepted answer since you got it first.

```
$ wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/8d/f8/9ccde77a90a30ef491bee431f157aee38dbd93b5f3c7545779a0acee71db/streamparse-3.0.1.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf streamparse-3.0.1.tar.gz
$ python streamparse-3.0.1/setup.py develop
```